# SQL Server or Access Database for ASP.NET web app?

Tags: asp.net, database

Using Access Database (*.mdb or *.accdb) is very simple. 
But I wonder about performance in comparison to using SQL Server in a production app with medium traffic websites!
Is it comparable to using SQLite with PHP?
Can you help me to choose?

Comment: just forget the word "Access" anytime you talk about "Production". SQL Server as backend database for web sites is ok, used in StackOverflow as well and as you see it out/over performs :)

Comment: Thanks you! I will change to it ....and try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 4+ years of web experience and my advice is do NOT go with Access on web, and even on desktop for apps with a considerable number of users, SQL Server is far stronger, faster, more scalable and is easy to use too...

You will find that using a different DB is not that different in the end, it just depends on your data access provider (EntityFramework, ADO .NET, etc)

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Access is garbage, plain and simple.